# How to generate dynamic id of <li>?

Tags: php, html, loops, auto-increment

I have one div which contain UL and LI. In this I want to generate dynamic IDs of that LI.
Right now I have used static HTML:

```
<li id= "nav-fragment-1">
<li id= "nav-fragment-2">
<li id= "nav-fragment-3">
<li id= "nav-fragment-4">
```

I want the same output, but dynamically. Now I'm bit confused how will I get this?

```
<div id="featured">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
<?php $i = 0; foreach($posts as $post): ?>
   <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1">
    <a href="<?php //echo $i++;) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escape($post['title']) ?>
<?php if($leads): ?>
      <p><?php echo $this->maxText($post['content'], 50, '...', true) ?></p>
    <?php endif ?></span>
  <img class="post-image" src="<?php echo $this->postImage($post['image'], '50px', '50px') ?>" alt="" title="<?php echo $this->escape($post['title']) ?>"/></a>
 </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add the value of $i in the id option of the li tag?

Comment: we don't know what `$post` is, or what it's contents are, so we can't help you. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1">
```

to:

```
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-<?php echo ++$i; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replya Davinder. I tried this code but it show me id="nav-fragment-5030" for all li.

Comment: @user599806 You are welcome.. Yeah it was tough.. competing with all the guys typing at a lightening speed.. an occurrence often seen when an relatively easy question is being asked.. :) Please accept an answer to help the visitors coming in future..

Comment: @user599806 please use the updated code in the answer. I typed $id instead of $i. I have edited the answer to make only one change.

Answer (score 1):

More details is required here, however you can use simple String functions:

```
<div id="featured">
 <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
  <?php $i = 0; foreach($posts as $post): ?>
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-<?php echo ++$i;?>">
  <a href="<?php //echo $i++;) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escape($post['title']) ?>
  <?php if($leads): ?>
  <p><?php echo $this->maxText($post['content'], 50, '...', true) ?></p>
  <?php endif ?></span>
  <img class="post-image" src="<?php echo $this->postImage($post['image'], '50px', '50px') ?>" alt="" title="<?php echo $this->escape($post['title']) ?>"/></a>
 </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

This should give you different id's for your `<li>` nav-fragment-1, 2 ,3

Comment: <?php echo $i; ?> will echo 0,1,2,3... not 1,2,3(What OP asked..), because initial value of `$i` is `0`

Comment: Yes that's correct, I am sorry for missing it. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the incrementing of `$i` just before the closing foreach loop to make the `id` of `li` increment by 1 each time the loop is repeated.

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($posts as $post): ?>
   <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-<?php echo $i + 1; ?>">
    <a href="#"><span><?php echo $this->escape($post['title']) ?>
<?php if($leads): ?>
      <p><?php echo $this->maxText($post['content'], 50, '...', true) ?></p>
    <?php endif ?></span>
  <img class="post-image" src="<?php echo $this->postImage($post['image'], '50px', '50px') ?>" alt="" title="<?php echo $this->escape($post['title']) ?>"/></a>
 </li>

<?php $i++; // important
endforeach ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $i; ?>` will echo 0,1,2,3... not 1,2,3(What OP asked..)

Comment: Aha.. Now I see you changed it :)

Comment: Yep. Didn't notice it the first time

Comment: Ok, but now your `$i++ // important` is not in <?php...?> tags.. `$i` will not increment.. Sorry for nitpicking... :)

Comment: Argh...my sleep deprecation is showing up. Thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Simply using `<?php echo ++$i; ?>` will eliminate the need for two lines. It will increment and echo

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-<?php echo $i ?>">
```

just dont forget to increment the $i at the end of the loop

Comment: <?php echo $i; ?> will echo 0,1,2,3... not 1,2,3(What OP asked..), because initial value of $i is 0.

Comment: Simply using <?php echo ++$i; ?> will eliminate the need for two lines. It will increment and echo

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<li class='ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected' id='nav-fragment-1'>
```

to

```
<?php echo "<li class='ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected' id='nav-fragment-$i'>"; ?>
```

Comment: Simply adding `$i` will not do the desired. The `<li>` code is out of PHP tags.

Comment: ya, i noticed that. and changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `<li>` tag with this if you want `nav-fragment-0`, `nav-fragment-1`, .... like this:

```
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-<?php echo $i++; ?>">
```

Comment: This is Wrong Answer. This does not output what OP wants. `echo $i++;` will echo `$i`'s initial value **first** and **then** increment it. I.e when `$i=0`, it will echo `0` and then increment `$i` to `1` Example: [Codepad.org/OHuTxQPI](http://codepad.org/OHuTxQPI) You should change it to `echo ++$i;` i.e. Increment and Echo